# Change link button color in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, datarepeater

I am using `Data Repeater` and `Link Button` inside `repeater` . I want to change the color of clicked `button` but it is not working . Here is my code.

```
<asp:Repeater  ID="rptPager" runat="server">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:LinkButton Font-Size="Larger" BackColor="Orange" ForeColor="White"  ID="lnkPage" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Text") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>'
                            CssClass=" btn"
                            OnClick="Page_Changed"></asp:LinkButton>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:Repeater>


protected void Page_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int pageIndex = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
    LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender;
    lnk.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    lnk.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

    this.GetImagesPageWise(pageIndex);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this way. Create class for Current Page LinkButton

```
.Active
{

    color:red;
     font:bold 12px Tahoma;

    }
```

Then Change the Repeater as following

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPager" runat="server">
                          <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Text") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>'
                                  Enabled='<%# Eval("Enabled") %>' OnClick="Page_Changed" CssClass='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Enabled")) == true ? "LBR" : "Active" %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                          </ItemTemplate>
                      </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptPager" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li class="<%#GetStatus(Eval("Enabled").ToString(),Eval("Text").ToString())%>">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Text") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>'
                                    Enabled='<%# Eval("Enabled") %>' OnClick="Page_Changed">
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>


Protected Function GetStatus(ByVal Enable As Boolean, ByVal linkName As String) As String
        Try
            If Enable = 0 And linkName <> "First" And linkName <> "Last" Then
                Return "active"
            Else
                Return ""
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ""
        End Try
    End Function
```